# Deep linking using React-Native

Tags: react-native

I need to open installed application (Android Games or Social Media like whatsapp ) from react-native project using deep link. I successfully open the Whatsapp , Facebook when i giving the below code

Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send');

Linking.openURL('fb://page/');

This will open the whatsapp send screen and facebook page.

I need to open all the installed application while click the button, based on the application name not using the screen name like "send" or "page" this is the application screen name.

If any possible ways to call the application based on their application name.? can you please any one help to solve this.

Comment: I think the other app must be used deep link WhatsApp application.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like share intent https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share

Comment: Sorry this will not work. I am looking on while click the button open the Android or IOS App. 
Example: